# Delete elements of numpy array by indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to delete a few rows of Numpy Array by indexes, but I couldn't figure out why it's resulting different values. It should remove three rows.

```
# The original array descritoresFaciais
[[ -9.30438712e-02   7.69939125e-02]   # index 0
[ -8.71469826e-02   9.11752135e-02]    # index 1    
[ -9.40909833e-02   1.10907182e-01]    # index 2
[ -1.45724729e-01   3.04837357e-02]    # index 3
[ -1.72051653e-01   5.80535792e-02]    # index 4
[ -1.44777581e-01   2.88028345e-02]]   # index 5

indexes = [0, 1, 2] # indexes I want to remove
x = np.delete(descritoresFaciais, indexes, axis=0)
print(x)

#Result of deleting
[[-0.14572473  0.01929282]
[-0.17205165  -0.00352619]
[-0.14477758   0.00853495]]
```

I also tried this command line but resulted the same values:

```
x = np.delete(descritoresFaciais, np.s_[0:3], axis=0)
```

Comment: Have you considered using lists? Numpy arrays are generally not meant to be used in such a manner, as they are allocated in contiguous memory and don't over-allocate (so they must be resized and reallocated when shrunk). Do you need to do fast math on the products? If not, maybe use lists?

Comment: The values are not changing. Actually the exponent format is converted into normal floating point value, compare it and you'll get to know.

Comment: Starting from the array you gave, I get the expected result with your code. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @amrs-tech The right-hand column changed values. (According to the question text anyway)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with NumPy 1.8.0, Python 3.6

Comment: @uneven_mark But I'm getting the right answer when I ran the code

Comment: Seems to work as expected using Python 3.5.2 and NumPy 1.16.3 as well. Getting the right answers.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers so far. If I delete only a row it works fine, but more than one IDK why it rounds the value. I might delete each row at time

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me..but as an alternative try defining the indices as a np.array themselves:

```
indexes = np.array([0,1,2])
x = np.delete(descritoresFaciais, indexes, axis=0)
```

if for some weird reason it's still not working..take the set difference between all rows and rows to delete, and return the rest of the array:

```
indexes = np.array([0,1,2])
allrows = np.array(range(len(descritoresFaciais)))
x = d[np.setdiff1d(allrows,indexes)]
```

I get the same answer your way and these 2 ways, so my gut says something weird happened when you defined your array or something changed before you tried to modify it